# Generate JSON from Meteor SimpleSchema or SwaggerSpec?

Tags: json, meteor, swagger, jsonschema, simple-schema

I have code in my meteor app to generate a schema for the collection:

```
Boards.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    autoValue() { 
      if (this.isInsert && !this.isSet) {
        let slug = 'board';
        const title = this.field('title');
        if (title.isSet) {
          slug = getSlug(title.value) || slug;
        }
        return slug;
      }
    },
  }
  ... // and so on
}
```

Is there a way i can generate and output / outprint a json schema or similar (opt. would be a swagger definiton spec) from this?

Comment: From the collection or from the schema? I usually have a seperate js file that contains the object that is passed to the schema, which acts as my api definition for the collection. This could be then parsed to JSON/Swagger using the common approaches.

Comment: Generating the json/swagger from either collection or simpleschema would both be acceptable.